# Failing to see the point of the Functional interfaces 'Consumer' and 'Supplier'

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-interface

I realize the uses of `Predicate` and `Function`, used for passing in a loosely-coupled conditional and function to a method respectively.

Predicates are frequently used for filtering java streams, e.g.

```
list.stream().filter(aPredicate).collect();
```

and Function:

```
list.stream().forEach(aFunction);
```

I don't see a similar use case for 'Consumer' and 'Supplier'. A simple example [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/03/java-8-consumer-supplier-explained-in-5-minutes/) has this code:

```
Consumer consumer = ConsumerTest::printNames;

consumer.accept("Jeremy");
consumer.accept("Paul");
consumer.accept("Richard");
```

where printNames is a simple method:

```
private static void printNames(String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

I don't see why I wouldn't just do:

```
Consumer consumer = ConsumerTest::printNames;

printNames("Jeremy");
printNames("Paul");
printNames("Richard");
```

Looks like unnecessary added code to me, perhaps that example does not show its power.

Comment: The linked example code is poor; it appears to be written by someone who doesn't understand Java's functional interfaces at all. Ironically, your example using the `forEach()` method is a relevant, simple example of the *right* way to use a `Consumer` (it doesn't use `Function`): `list.forEach(ConsumerTest::printNames)`

Comment: Have a look at the [Supplier javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).  At the very top of the page is a blue navigation bar.  The fifth word in that navigation bar is USE.  [Follow that link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/class-use/Supplier.html), and you will see plenty of justifications for the existence of Supplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of `list.stream().forEach(aFunction);` is actually wrong, `forEach` takes a `Consumer<? super T>` and not a `Function<T,R>`

The point of these functional interfaces is all about the **shape** of the functions, in other words the inputs & outputs of these interfaces.

To use the interfaces you provided:

`Predicate<T>` input: value of type T, output: boolean, used by `filter` a lot.

`Function<T,R>` input: value of type T, output: value of type R. Kinda like a transformation, used by `map` a lot.

`Consumer<T>` input: value of type T, output: void/nothing. Used by `forEach` a lot, in situations where you just want to print something out, or persist the value to a database/file where you don't really care about the return value.

`Supplier<T>` input: nothing, output: value of type T. This is probably the least common because people often start with a Collection when they use lambda. But Supplier is useful when you want to generate your own stream, for example, if you want to generate an infinite stream of prime numbers, there will be no way to do that by starting with a List.

Answer (score 2):

Another concrete example of a supplier is when a new Object is needed for a function, created on the spot, such as for the [`Collectors.toCollection(Supplier<C> factory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-).  For example:

```
List<T> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));
```

Here, we pass a “supplier” ... a function taking no arguments, returning a value ... to the `toCollection` method.

Without the `Supplier` type, we couldn’t express that.